# Can´t install Canvas (npm) on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, canvas, npm, cairo

I installed GTK+2 as instructed here: https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/wiki/Installation---Windows

I installed libjpeg-turbo

I installed Visual Studio 2015 Community

I installed node-gyp: npm install -g node-gyp

But when I run node-gyp rebuild I get:
Cannot open source file: '..\src\Canvas.cc': No such file or directory ... my_project_folder\build\canvas.vcxproj]

And when I run npm install canvas I get:
node-gyp\src\win_delay_load_hook.c(34): error C2373: '__pfnDliNotifyHook2': redefinition; different type modifiers ... my_project_folder\node_modules\canvas\build\canvas.vcxproj]

I am almost giving up... so easy on mac and linux... this is hell

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with it too at some point, The issue was resolved for me by running the npm command using "MSBuild Command Prompt for VS2015" (which should have being installed as part of Visual Studio 2015 installation which you did)

Comment: Didn´t work, still getting: "'__pfnDliNotifyHook2': redefinition; different type modifiers" when npm install